# a problem when get Number type in Dictionary (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

here is my plist and code

```
> <plist version="1.0">
>     <dict>
>      <key>Title</key>
>      <string>News</string>
>      <key>icon</key>
>      <integer>0</integer>
>     </dict>
>     </plist>




int i = [dictionary objectForKey:@"icon"];
NSLog(@"%d",i);
```

log result is 81841904
why it not 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objectForKey` returns a reference, not an integer.  I *believe* that it's returning a `NSNumber` in this case.  You can get an integer value out of that.

Comment: which function that i can use to get NSNumber?

thanks for you advise Corey Porter

Answer (score 7):

Corey is correct. Note the word "object" in the `-objectForKey:` method; in this case, that'll indeed be an `NSNumber`. What you should be doing is

```
 int i = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"icon"] intValue];
```